# Log.e does not print the stack trace of UnknownHostException

Tags: android, logcat

Calling `Log.e(TAG, "some message", e)` where `e` is an `UnknownHostException`, does not print the stack trace on the logcat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since May 20, 2011, there is a change in the `Log` class, such that `UnknownHostException` exceptions are not printed.

> This is to reduce the amount of log spew that apps do in the non-error
>   condition of the network being unavailable.
>   https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/dba50c7ed24e05ff349a94b8c4a6d9bb9050973b

Comment: @SatelliteSD I tried to but SO told me I need to wait 2 days. I put it here since I didn't find this problem mentioned elsewhere. Even the Android docs didn't mention about this =(

Comment: This seems completely inappropriate!

If I do:
`Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Ouch!", throwable)`

I expect the exception message and traceback to *always* be logged.

At the very least I'd expect this to be elided down to "Unknown host: foo.bar", not simply have the entire message and stack go away!!!

Answer (score -3):

The `e` you are including is useless, remove it and it would be visible in `logcat`.

```
Log.e(TAG, "some message");
```

Comment: No. It works, there was no error, but the stack trace is not printed on the logcat.

Comment: @yuku oh! It was my mistake, and up to I know, only two parameters are allowed in log.e

Comment: No, you can most definitely log a stacktrace http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable)